# How correctly pass arguments to the SQL request via the sqlx package in Golang?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

In my **Golang** (1.15) application I use [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) package to work with the **PostgreSQL** database (PostgreSQL 12.5).

When I try to execute SQL statement with arguments PostgreSQL database it raises an error:

> ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1 (SQLSTATE 42P18):
> PgError null

According to the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/errcodes-appendix.html), this error means that an `INDETERMINATE DATATYPE` was passed.

The `organizationId` has value. It's not null/nil or empty. Also, its data type is a simple built-in data type `*string`.

*Code snippet with Query method*:

```golang
rows, err := cr.db.Query(`
    select
        channels.channel_id::text,
        channels.channel_name::text
    from
        channels
    left join organizations on
        channels.organization_id = organizations.organization_id
    where
        organizations.tree_organization_id like concat( '%', '\', $1, '%' );`, *organizationId)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I also tried to use `NamedQuery` but it also raise error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" (SQLSTATE 42601): PgError null

*Code snippet with NamedQuery method*:

```golang
args := map[string]interface{}{"organization_id": *organizationId}

rows, err := cr.db.NamedQuery(`
    select
        channels.channel_id::text,
        channels.channel_name::text
    from
        channels
    left join organizations on
        channels.organization_id = organizations.organization_id
    where
        organizations.tree_organization_id like concat( '%', '\', :organization_id, '%' );`, args)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

In all likelihood, the arguments is not passed correctly to my request. Can someone explain how to fix this strange behavior?

**P.S.** I must say right away that I do not want to form an sql query through `concatenation`, or through the `fmt.Sprintf` method. It's not safe.

Comment: PostgreSQL cannot deduce the type of $1.  Try this: concat( '%', '\', $1::text, '%' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution of this problem.

I found the [discussion](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/138#issuecomment-102245206) in github repository of the *sqlx* package.

In the **first option**, we can make concatenation of our search string outside of the query. This should still be safe from injection attacks.

The **second choice** to try this: `concat( '%', '\', $1::text, '%' )`. As  Bjarni Ragnarsson said in the comment, PostgreSQL cannot deduce the type of `$1`.